# MailChimp extension v2.0.1 won't install on CiviCRM 5.3.2

Tags: civimail, extension, mailchimp

The latest stable release of the [MailChimp extension for CiviCRM](https://civicrm.org/extensions/mailchimp-civicrm-integration) isn't installing on our Civi 5.3.2 via the Civi internal extension installer. Admin interface displays

> Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the
>   moment. You may want to contact your administrator or service provider
>   with more details about what action you were performing when this
>   occurred. DB Error: unknown error

PHP error log shows no related errors. Also getting the following when coming back to the Civi admin interface after checking the log:

[image: Civi alert messages]

UDATE: On my fifth or sixth attempt to install, it finally worked. Didn't change anything prior to this. No idea why.

Comment: Any extension marked as compatible with 4.7 should also be compatible with CiviCRM 5.0+.  It might be worth editing your question to indicate what the error message/log entries are when you try to install Mailchimp on 5.3.2.

Comment: Also - I was able to successfully install Mailchimp on both 5.3.2 and 5.5alpha.

Answer (score 1):

Crazy as it sounds, this is one case in which it may be advisable to repeat the same behavior and expect different results. There's no clear or obvious reason why the installer failed repeatedly, but on the fifth or sixth attempt, it finally worked. Memory glitch on the remote server? Hiccup in the CPU? Who knows. But if you encounter the same issue, try and try again, and hopefully you'll get the desired outcome sooner or later.